# URN/URI For Software Manufacturer/Product/Version

Tags: logging, uri, rfc, urn

I am working on extending a current logger solution that I would like to include more information than just class, line number, log level, date, etc.  I would like to also capture the host name, the manufacturer of the software that generated the log message, the software product name, the version of the software, and the code library.

My searches have turned up nothing other than a user-agent string. Does there already exist a standard way (RFC/URN/URI) of communicating this information?

urn:xyz:myhost/microsoft/windows-7.0/outlook-10.1/smtp-0.2

Comment: Communicating in what context? A generic HTTP request?

Comment: Recording to a log file so that I may know which version of the software generated the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like syslog.
Check this [RFC5424 The Syslog Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)

Comment: This is not exactly what I am seeking, but the RFC was very helpful and I have lifted some ideas from it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @davidemm. According to your question, it seems that you're collecting log data from different systems into a central repository. Syslog is just right for this, and it is a widely used standard. For windows , there is also a eventlog-to-syslog program, which 'provides a method of sending Windows Eventlog events to a syslog server.'  link -- https://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/